# I need to make a graph using hashmap in java but my code shows nullpointer exception in addEdge function

Tags: java, arraylist, graph, nullpointerexception, hashmap

```
public class graph {

private class node {
    String label;
    node(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public String getNode() {
        return label;
    }
}

private HashMap<node, ArrayList<node>> graph = new HashMap<>();

public void addNode(String label) {
    graph.putIfAbsent(new node(label), new ArrayList<>());
}

public void removeNode(String label) {
    Iterator<node> itr = graph.keySet().iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        if(itr.next().getNode() == label) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
}

public void addEdge(String src, String des) {
    graph.get(src).add(new node(des));
}

public void removeEdge(String src, String des) {
    if(!graph.get(src).isEmpty()) 
        graph.get(src).forEach((n) -> remove(n, des));
}

private void remove(node n, String des) {
    if(n.getNode() == des)
        n = null;
}

public void printGraph() {
    System.out.println(graph);
}
```

}

i'm using java version 8. I think the problem is either in addNode or addEdge function, but i'm unable to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please share the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

For the very first edge that will be added to the `graph` it will throw a NullpointerException because it doesn't have any former edge to add to

```
public void addEdge(String src, String des) {
    graph.get(src).add(new node(des));
}
```

---

```
ArrayList<node> nodes = graph.get(src); <- NPE here
```

calling any method on this **nodes** object causes NPE for the very first time u try to add an edge because the nodes object is *null*.

I think you need to make a decision on what would be the `src` for the very first edge